# Java array[] with unknow size - what's wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, class, nullpointerexception

```
ImageItem imageItems[] = new ImageItem[data.length()]; 

for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.e("RESPONSE INFO::::", "id:" + object.get("id").toString());

        imageItems[i].imageId     = object.get("id").toString();    //NullPointerException
        imageItems[i].imageURI    = object.get("source").toString();
        imageItems[i].thumbURI    = object.get("picture").toString();
        imageItems[i].createdTime = object.get("created_time").toString();
        imageItems[i].link        = object.get("link").toString();

}
```

Above is some kind of banal problem that can't resolve. Im still getting the **NullPointerException** at line with comment. At first I thought somethin's wrong with JSONobjects, but I'm sure that `object.get("id").toString();` returns the right String. Something must be wrong with `imageItems[]` array.

ImageItem is a simple class with few String fields:

```
public class ImageItem {
    public String imageId = null;
    public String imageURI = null;
    public String thumbURI = null;
    public String createdTime = null;
    public String link = null;
}
```

Any ideas what i'm missing here?

**EDIT:** I should mention that the ImageItem class is inner class of another class AlbumGallery. Now I'm getting error: ***No enclosing instance of type AlbumGallery is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type AlbumGallery (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of AlbumGallery).*** with `imageItems[i] = new ImageItem()`

Comment: `imageItems` is full of `null` values, since you haven't put anything in it yet.

Comment: I dont understand, im putting values here: 'imageItems[i].imageId     = object.get("id").toString();'

Comment: `imageItems[i]` is `null`. Accessing `imageItems[i].imageId` is invalid.

Comment: Yep, you need to assign an ImageItem to each imageItems array entry before using it.

Comment: Make sure to search for error messages. They've all been encountered by someone in some form already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at the top of your for loop add `imageItems[i] = gallery.new ImageItem()`

Comment: np, hit the accept button if it solved the problem properly :)

Comment: wait, it gives me this error: **No enclosing instance of type AlbumGallery is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type AlbumGallery (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of AlbumGallery).**

Comment: 'new ImageItem()' is underlined and shows this error wen mouse pointer is over it.

Comment: what is the code for albumgallery and do you have a constructor for ImageItem?
Should just have to do `instanceofalbumgallery.new ImageItem()`

Comment: @Incredible - The problem is that you made ImageItem an inner class of some other class.  Inner classes are really cool (at least some people think that), but they're kinda hard to use if you're a novice.

Comment: no i don't have constructor. i thought so simple class doesnt need constructor

Comment: @Hot Licks - exactly. is there any solution to let this class as inner class?

Comment: @Incredible you just have to do `X.new ImageItem()` where X is an instance of the outer class (in this case AlbumGallery), you should be able to do `this.new ImageItem()` if you are inside AlbumGallery as I suspect you are

Comment: No, Im in Fragment class and ImageItem is in AlbumGallery. I want to pass imageItems[] array as a parameter for instance of AlbumGallery.

Comment: @Incredible, you have to instantiate the outer class before you can do the inner class
take a look at docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: It is instantiated by `gallery = (AlbumGallery) view.findViewById(R.id.albumGallery);`

Comment: that would make gallery an instance of AlbumGallery yes
so try `gallery.new ImageItem()`